# Where is MicrosoftAjax.js located/did something just change in SharePoint Online?

Tags: javascript

I am using SharePoint Online and was referencing the MicrosoftAjax.js file via /_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js for the past several weeks without issue. A week later and no changes to the system and it is now not working/can't be found when I try to browse to it. Where is MicrosoftAjax.js located within SharePoint Online? I don't want to use the CDN.

I've also noticed that I can open it from an on premises site via /_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MicrosoftAjax.js file has been rolled back to where it was. The issue should be resolved now. A process has been working on to prevent it from happen again.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2013 (Online and on-prem) added a version number to the _layouts path. Try /_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js

Comment: I tried that as well, but have the same issue... A missing file/404. Is there a feature that needs to be enabled to slow access?

Comment: No, you can't add files to the system folders by activating a Feature. I checked my SharePoint Online tenant and MicrosoftAjax.js is there at /_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js

Comment: Odd. I will have to check again, as I don't understand what could have changed. Maybe something is affecting my tenant.

Comment: I just tested another tenant and it is working fine. It must be my tenant.

Comment: We just noticed this in our tenant as well.  This file was there a week a ago.  Our developer goes on vacation and he notices that it's no longer there when he returns. (!)  
  
Our tenant build information is:
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
vti_buildversion:SR|16.0.4107.1212  
  
(which can be seen here: /_vti_pvt/buildversion.cnf)

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with Microsoft, they decided to remove this core file without notification, as they believed it was not in a lot of use, when in reality it affects a lot of users/developers. They have promised a KB article and solution in the near future, but for immediate help, you can use the CDN or pull the down the hard script from the CDN:

https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js